# Redirecting to home route after sending get request to nested resource controller in laravel

Tags: php, routes, nested, resources, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to reach to my nested resource controller by passing this url in postman with get method :

```
http://peoject.local/api/admin/users/4/seats
```

my api.php file is like :

```
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
        Route::resource('users', 'Admin\UsersController', ['except' => ['store', 'create', 'edit']]);

        Route::resource('users.seats', 'Admin\ASeatController', ['only' => ['index', 'show', 'update', 'destroy']]);

        Route::resource('banners', 'Admin\BannersController', ['except' => ['edit', 'create']]);
    });
```

I want to get the user id in ASeatController :

```
/**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @param $userId
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index($userId)
    {

        try {
            $statusCode = 200;

            $domains = Seat::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->first();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $statusCode = 400;
        } finally {
            $response = \Response::json($domains, $statusCode);
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

But when I test it I redirect to /home, and I don't know why. I followed official laravel docs to do this.

Any Idea how to fix this ?

FYI : I'm using laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Fixed it. first was cashing of postman I don't know why I restarted postman and it started to work. then for selecting from databases I had to put intval() in my query like :

```
$domains = Seat::where('user_id', '=', intval($userId))->first();
```